# RecursiveIterator not working as expected

Tags: php, recursiveiterator

Here is my function:

```
protected function getContents($absoluteDirectoryPath = false, $recursive = false, $filter = "/.$/") {
    if(!$absoluteDirectoryPath) return false;
    $iterator  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($absoluteDirectoryPath));
    $files = new RegexIterator($iterator, $filter);
    return $iterator;
}
```

And i call it like this:

```
$pageFiles = $this->getContents($pagepath);

foreach($pageFiles as $file) {
    echobr("PageFile: " . $file->fileName);
}
```

This is the error I get:

`Notice:  Undefined property: SplFileInfo::$fileName`

If I var_dump `$pageFiles` I get this:

```
object(DirectoryIterator)#5 (4) {
  ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(68) "/home/domain/example/public/home/home.php"
  ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
  string(12) "home.php"
  ["glob":"DirectoryIterator":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["subPathName":"RecursiveDirectoryIterator":private]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Whats going on? Why can't I loop through the results? There are 4 files in this directory and I should be able to output the filename.

Comment: `fileName`, not `filename`.

Comment: @tkausl sorry, I edited after the fact.  Still get an error.

Answer (score 2):

The [`SplFileInfo` class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) does not have a (public) `filename` or `fileName` property. However, it has a [`getFilename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php) method. You can use it to get the filename:

```
foreach($pageFiles as $file) {
    echobr("PageFile: " . $file->getFilename());
}
```